# Next.js warning: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am developing an e-commerce site using Nextjs and working on viewing myCart page (list of ordered items)

The code for 'http://localhost:5000/myCart' is given below:
myCart page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from '../public/css/MyCart.module.scss';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import OrderCard from '../components/OrderCard';
import Router from 'next/router';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

// let customerName = '';
// let customerMail = '';
// let data;
let key;
// let dta2;
let arr1 = [];

function orderCard(arr1) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.item_group} key={arr1._id}>
        <OrderCard
          id={arr1._id}
          item={arr1.itemName}
          menu={String(arr1.menuId)}
          img={arr1.itemPic}
          summary={arr1.summary}
          size={String(arr1.itemSize)}
          qtty={String(arr1.qtty)}
          price={String(arr1.itemPrice)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function MakeGetRequest(props) {
  const arr1 = props.bpi.myList;
  const customerMail = props.bpi.userMail;
  const customerName = props.bpi.userName;

  console.log(customerMail, customerName);
  console.log(`myList: ${arr1}`);

  function handleCheckout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.textContent = 'Processing...';
    Router.replace('/checkout_form');
  }

  if (!arr1 || arr1 === 'undefined') {
    // console.log(`In myCart makeGetRequest with arr1 ${arr1}`);
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout title="My Cart">
          {/* <Link href="/">
            <a className={styles.toHome}>&larr; Back to home </a>
          </Link> */}
          <Container className={styles.container}>
            <main className={styles.main}>
              <h1
                className={styles.heading_secondary}
                id={styles.heading_secondary}
              >
                Your cart is empty. Please click on back to home and select
                items.
              </h1>
            </main>
          </Container>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const arrLen = arr1.length;
  // dta2 = arrLen;

  // console.log(dta2);

  const qttyTotal = arr1.reduce(
    (totalQtty, arrQty) => totalQtty + arrQty.qtty,
    0
  );

  const amtTotal = arr1.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev + curr.qtty * curr.itemPrice;
  }, 0);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   dta2 = arrLen;
  // }, [arrLen]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout title="My Cart">
        <div>
          <div className={styles['customer-details']}>
            <h3 className={styles.cartName}>Cart of {customerName}</h3>
            <p className={styles['customer-details']}>{customerMail}</p>
          </div>
          <Container className={styles.container}>
            <section className={styles.section_cartList}>
              {/* <div className={styles.row0}> */}
              <div className={`${styles['col_1_of_2']} ${styles['col-1']}`}>
                <div className={`${styles['grid']} ${styles['menu-item']}`}>
                  <div key="{item}"> {arr1.map(orderCard)}</div>

                  {/* {arr1.map(orderCard)} */}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={`${styles['col_1_of_2']} ${styles['col-2']}`}>
                <div className={styles.heading}>
                  <h2
                    className={styles.heading_secondary}
                    id={styles.heading_secondary}
                  >
                    SUMMARY
                  </h2>
                  <h3 className={styles.itemsTotalP}>No. of items</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.itemsTotal}>{arrLen}</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.qttyTotalP}>No. of dishes</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.qttyTotal}>{qttyTotal}</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.amtTotalP}>Total amount (US$):</h3>
                  <h3 className={styles.amtTotal}>{amtTotal}</h3>
                </div>
                <button
                  className={`${styles['label']} ${styles['btnCart']}`}
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleCheckout}
                >
                  CHECKOUT
                </button>
              </div>
            </section>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

MakeGetRequest.getInitialProps = async (req, res, ctx) => {
  res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/myCart');

  let data = await res.json();

  console.log(`In getInitialProps: ${data.userMail}`);

  return { bpi: data };
};

export default MakeGetRequest;
```

I have a cart icon in the Navigation bar. When I click on it I am navigated to myCart page. The ordered list is properly displayed. But on inspecting the console in Dev Tools I see the below-given warning.

Again when I click on the cart icon, the page refreshes and displays correctly. At this point, the browser reads http://localhost:5000/myCart. This is the same URL while clicking on the cart.

But surprisingly, if I refresh the browser by clicking on the icon near the URL space, the page does not display correctly. On checking, I observed that myList from the backend is not transferred to the front end.

My backend code:

```
async function displayCartDetails(req, res, next) {
  // 1) Getting token and check if it's there

  if (!req.cookies.token) {
    return res.status(423).json({
      status: 'Failed',
      msg: 'You are not logged in. Please login.',
    });
  }

  const tokenValue = req.cookies.token;
  // console.log(`token found ${tokenValue}`);

  const decoded = jwt.verify(tokenValue, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

  const userId = decoded._id;

  // console.log(`userId: ${userId}`);

  const user = await User.findById(decoded._id);

  console.log(`user: ${user}`);

  cartSelected = user.cartId;
  // console.log(`In userController cartSelected: ${cartSelected}`);

  const userName = user.name;
  // console.log(`In userController: ${userName}`);

  const userMail = user.email;
  //   console.log(`In userController: ${userMail}
  // `);

  myList = await Cart.find({ _id: { $in: cartSelected } });

  if (!myList) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      msg: 'Some error occurred. Please try again later.',
    });
  }

  console.log(`myList: ${myList}`);

  // const { myList, userName, userMail } = user;

  return res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    myList: myList,
    userName,
    userMail,
    user: { myList, userName, userMail },
    // token,
  });
}
```

Again if I click on the cart icon, the page is correctly displayed.

The below warning always displayed.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MakeGetRequest`. See ...fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in Fragment (created by MakeGetRequest)
    in MakeGetRequest (at _app.js:5)
    in MyApp
    in ErrorBoundary (created by ReactDevOverlay)
    in ReactDevOverlay (created by Container)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Root
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2430
printWarning @ react.development.js?72d0:315
error @ react.development.js?72d0:287
validateExplicitKey @ react.development.js?72d0:1630
validateChildKeys @ react.development.js?72d0:1656
createElementWithValidation @ react.development.js?72d0:1806
MakeGetRequest @ myCart.js?4849:105
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:14803
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:17482
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:18596
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23179
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:22154
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21756
eval @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11089
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js?3069:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11039
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11084
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11072
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21199
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:24373
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:24774
render @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:24840
renderReactElement @ index.tsx?8abf:473
doRender @ index.tsx?8abf:719
_callee2$ @ index.tsx?8abf:360
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:21
render @ index.js:425
subscription @ index.tsx?8abf:318
notify @ router.ts?35b8:1228
set @ router.ts?35b8:1019
_callee$ @ router.ts?35b8:816
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?c973:21
change @ router.js:727
push @ router.ts?35b8:571
instance.<computed> @ router.ts?06ff:165
linkClicked @ link.tsx?5e4b:145
onClick @ link.tsx?5e4b:317
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:389
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3287
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3259
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3514
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21871
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:795
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4267
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4189
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js?3069:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11039
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21887
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4168
Show 13 more frames
```

Request for proper guidance. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding a key to the fragment, so the mapped 'orderCard' components don't have a key on the outer-most element. Try replacing your fragments with keyed fragments like so.

````
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={arr1._id}>
      <div className={styles.item_group}>
        <OrderCard
          id={arr1._id}
          item={arr1.itemName}
          menu={String(arr1.menuId)}
          img={arr1.itemPic}
          summary={arr1.summary}
          size={String(arr1.itemSize)}
          qtty={String(arr1.qtty)}
          price={String(arr1.itemPrice)}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}```
````